# Adding a row with bigger height to Spinner adds padding to bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner

I would like to build this dropdown layout:

[image: Spinner]

To be able to add the top and bottom padding of 8dp I used the following code:

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    if (convertView == null) {
        if (position == 0) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row_top, null);
        } else if (position == (getCount() - 1)) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row_bottom, null);
        } else
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, null);
    }

    TextView title =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_row_textview);
    title.setText(data.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

However this adds a padding to the bottom of the Spinner. I guess the padding is added because the Spinner calculates it's dropdown height based on the first element and since the following elements have lower heights a padding remains at the bottom.
[image: Layout result]

EDIT: 
Here's the xml of the Spinner row:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_row_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

The top and bottom xml files have their minHeight and layout_height set to 56dp and have a padding of 8 at the top/bottom.

And here's the spinner:

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"/>
```

Any ideas how I could remove the bottom padding?

Comment: Can you post the XML code for the spinner and the spinner items?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include them. Added them now :)

Comment: It looks to be your problem is that you are loading different layouts for the top, bottom and middle row. I don't see the XML for the other layouts, matter of fact I don't know what layout applies to the XML you've provided, but if the layouts are different especially for the last item, that would cause the issue you're seeing. In the original image you got from the Material Design spec all of the Spinner items have the exact same layout.

Comment: The provided xml file is for the middle rows. As I mentioned above the other two xmll files are the same, they just contain a padding of 8 dp and are 8 dp higher.
I added 3 different layouts for the rows since on the first row I need a padding of 8 at the top and on the last row I need a padding of 8 on the bottom.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Why do you need to have three different layouts? Also what happens if you just use the same layout for all row types?

Comment: Well, I couldn't add the padding of 8 dp to the first and last element if I always use the same layout. I tried to add a padding to the Spinner, but that didn't work either

Comment: To achieve what you want, adding padding will cause the View's internal content to be offset. Which is why in your example, the "Refresh" TextView is spaced further down then the other TextViews. But I just checked my code using spinner and my content display with my views centered with no extra padding. Try using an ArrayAdapter with the spinner and pass in "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" as the layoutResource.

Comment: To further expand on my padding point. When you add padding to a View, it cause it's internal content such as any children views or drawing to be offset. For example, adding padding left and top padding to a TextView will cause the text to be pushed to the right and the bottom but the actual TextView will still be drawn with the same size at the same x and y locations.  Margins actually will preserve the views drawing bounds and instructs it's parent layout to offset the entire Views position relative to parent and any other siblings.

Comment: Would ArrayAdapter allow to use different layout files for the rows? I do understand what padding does, and the first row is how I wanted it to be. The problem is the space at the bottom of the spinner, after the About element.

Comment: With using an ArrayAdapter you are stuck using one layout type, unless you extend the class but doing that, you might as well use a custom adapter any ways. I was recommending using the ArrayAdapter and see if you get the padding issue, because looking at you XML I don't see where that additional margin at the bottom is coming from.