# Spinner padding only when open

Tags: android, xml, spinner, android-spinner

I am trying to build this spinner layout.
[image: Material spinner]

I added the padding of 8 dp to the bottom and to the top programaticaly in the `getDropDownView()` method of the Adapter:

```
 public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, null);
    }

    TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_row_textview);
    title.setText(items.get(position));
    parent.setPadding(0, dpToPx(8), 0, dpToPx(8));
    return row;
}
```

The problem is that setting the parents padding also adds a padding to the `Spinners` closed view and the `getView()` method is not called when the `Spinner` is closed to reset it.
Any ideas on how I could apply the padding only when the Spinner's dropdown is open?

Comment: rather adding padding to parent try to add padding to the convertview but before adding padding to the convert view check if that is the first position. Hope that will help you

Comment: I already tried that approach, but that added a padding to the bottom. I didn't found out the cause of that padding. I posted a question about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754037/adding-a-row-with-bigger-height-to-spinner-adds-padding-to-bottom?noredirect=1#comment82508543_47754037

Comment: this is happening due to arguments passed in setPadding method. You are passing 2 arguments. first for top and second for bottom. But you are intended to add padding only top....if you want to add padding to the bottom view as well. You need to check if the position is last. if last then only add padding for the last item

Comment: Note that I'm adding the padding to the parent and not to the current row. As I mentioned above with the position check I had the problem with the padding on the bottom of the dropdown shown in the other question. Also, the top padding should also be removed when the Spinner is closed.

Comment: I found a solution: resetting the adapter in the onItemSelected() method. But I'll leave this question unanswered because this is a workaround and not a clean way to solve this

Comment: And the above solution only works if the spinner has a smaller size than the screen. Otherwise the scrolling won't work.